# Is there a reward if I find all stars in The Talos Principle?

Tags: the-talos-principle

I've noticed that each world has a number of stars (secrets). I was wondering whether there is a reward if I find all of them?

> For example there is a room in the A world hub which is opened when I find the first star but I don't know about any other unlocks beyond this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Each world hub has a hidden area that requires 10 stars to unlock.

> Each of these contains several puzzles that give you gray sigils.  Each area also has a sign with a single-digit number on it.

Once you have those

> In the tower, there is a code panel on floor 1 near one of the elevators that unlocks it.  Enter in the 3 digits you found in the secret areas. This takes you to floor 6 of the tower.

and then

> You use the gray sigils to complete a final tetronimo puzzle to reach the game's secret ending.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but if I finish the game with the standard ending it won't delete my progress right? I can get to the secret ending after it right?

Comment: @AdamArold Correct.

Comment: I don't get it. I achieved the ending which you get when you climb the tower but nor the code nor the gray sigils were needed.

Comment: @AdamArold That's probably not the secret ending since it doesn't require finding any secrets.

Answer (score 2):

Behind the door is another door that requires 10 stars to open. There is one of those doors in each hub area. Behind each of those doors is an additional area with more puzzles.